Issue with Replacing Password Variables in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I have a YAML project file that contains the configuration for my data testing tool, CAT.
Part of this configuration includes connection strings to Power BI reports, which contain the data I am testing. I use variables for many parts of the connection strings, including the user password, like this:

I have set up the passwords in the Azure DevOps Library for the classic pipeline and all variables are being replaced correctly except for the password variable.
The error message indicates that the agent cannot find it.
Pipeline code:

Error message:

Varibales set up:

I’m unsure what might be causing the issue with the JUST password variable replacement.
Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem?

Hi @HelenaNovakova, Welcome to SO. Have you got a chance to go through the answers below to double check your environment variables? If the answers don't work for you. Would you share your pipeline YAML definition with your script is there is any and let us know which step had incurred the error? Thx for the sharing.

By "YAML project file" you mean CAT project file, right? Then one piece of information is missing - is your Azure DevOps pipeline a classic pipeline (you define it in GUI) or is it YAML? Can you share the step that leads to the error? (either screenshot or YAML).

Based on your connection strings content and the error message, the connection string is reading the Environment Variables from Pipeline and the Secret Password Variable not be read.
The cause of the issue can be that the Secret variables are not written to the pipeline environment variables by default.
To use the secret variable in Azure Pipeline, you need to explicitly map secret variables.
For example: You can add the env field in the task definition to map secret variable.
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: 'filename'
  env:
    PBIServicePrincipalPassword: $(PBIServicePrincipalPassword)

For more detailed info, you can refer to the doc: Set secret variables

Hi Kevin, you were right there was an issue with secret variables settings. Thanks so much"

You haven't shared a minimal reproducible sample YAML pipeline defintion; it is difficult to understand which pipeline task had incurred the error, how you would expect the pipeline to read the environment variables (perhaps) and then replace the Password in the ConnectionString with the value of the environment variable %PBIServicePrincipalPassword%.
From the screenshot, you highlighted the variable in your variable group with the name PBIServicePrincipalPassword_DP which was a different variable from PBIServicePrincipalPassword. Please double check if you have defined the password value for the correct variable and consumed it in your connection string.

Hi, thanks for spotting this, I have corrected the printscreen and added more pictures, to clarify my issue . I hope its more understandable  now .

Thanks for the update. May I know if the pipeline used to work, say in your classic pipeline? Have you tested with the suggestion by Kevin in above to add env property for your pwsh task?
